# How to write a code to solve my ODE problem?

Tags: differential-equations, code-request

I have the ODE:

$$y''+\lambda y = B^3\sin^3(\sqrt{\lambda}x) \ y(0)=0, \int_0^1 y(x)\sin(n\pi x)dx=0$$

I am not sure how to write the mathematica code to solve this ODE, obviously I need here DSolve but how to incorporate the integral condition?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The integral condition can be thought as a normalization condition to determine the constant of integration. For example

```
f = DSolveValue[{y''[x] + λ y[x] == B^3 Sin[Sqrt[λ] x]^3,y[0] == 0}, y, x]
```

[image]
And the constant of integration `C[2]` can be determined by

```
eqn = Integrate[f[x]*Sin[n π x], {x, 0, 1}] == 0 // Simplify;
Solve[eqn, C[2]] // Simplify
```

[image]

As pointed out by Winther, the expression can be further simplified if n is an integer

```
Simplify[%, n ∈ Integers]
```

[image]

Comment: It's very likely $n$ is an integer for this problem. In that case doing a `Simplify[%, n \[Element] Integers]` is also very useful to further simplify the expression since $\sin(n\pi) = 0$ and $\cos(n\pi) = (-1)^n$.

Comment: @Winther Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3):

```
sol = DSolve[ {y''[x] + λ y[x] == B^3  Sin[Sqrt[λ] x]^3 , y[0] == 0, 
       Integrate[y[z] Sin[n π z], {z, 0, 1}] == 0}, y[x], x];

y[x] /. sol
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]